# What is the asymptotic behavior of the two quarks interaction in the limit of small distances and in the limit of long distances?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, confinement

quantum chromodynamics. It is known that at small distances two quarks do not interact and interaction remains constant at large distances. So the question stands: What is the asymptotic behavior of the two quarks interaction in the limit of small distances and in the limit of long distances?

I would accept an answer like "this is still an open question in the theory..."

Comment: Behavior as regards what aspect, gluon interactions  something like that? No offence intended, but its a very broad question as it stands......unless we have so little data, then its not so broad : )